# Проблема с регулярным выражением получением числа

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мое регулярное выражение:

```reg
\[([А-Я][а-я] [а-я]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4})\] .* file:(.*)
```

Оно правильно парсит строку вида:

```txt
[Пт мар 25 12:12:24 2021] [Processing] - Обработка: Запущена часть обработки file://path.txt
```

Но регулярное выражение не находит ничего, если дата имеет такой вид:

```txt
[Пт мар 5 12:12:24 2021]
```

Тоесть для строки

```txt
[Пт мар 25 12:12:24 2021] [Processing] - Обработка: Запущена часть обработки file://path.txt с кадра 17234 по кадр -1\n
```

мое регулярное выражение не сработает. Как мне изменить регулярное выражение, чтобы оно обрабатывало строку с любой датой (число имеет 1 или 2 символа).

Answer (score 4):

`[0-9]{2}` -> `[0-3]?[0-9]`

`?` Означает 0 или 1 символ.

*Числа от 32 до 39 тоже удовлетворяют этому выражению. Если входные данные валидные, то это не имеет значения.*